# Iterating through a string and returning "x" number of characters in the string

Tags: python, loops

Im trying to iterate through a string and return the string length that has been declared in the function.

It will receive two parameters, x and chars. The function will return a string that is comprised of the values in chars from index 0 up to the index x-1.

The return I want to receive is

```
print rangeLoopStringParam1("bobsyouruncle", 5)
# -> "bobsy"
print rangeLoopStringParam1("supercalifragilisticexpialidoshus", 8)
# -> "supercal"
```

This is the code I have so far but I feel like Im not getting very far. Can anyone guide me through this problem?

```
def rangeLoopStringParam1(chars, x):
    for i in range(0, x, len(chars)):
        chars += chars
    return chars
```

Comment: why not just `'bobsyouruncle'[0:5]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whats wrong with [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)?

```
def stringRange(chars, x):
    return chars[:x]
```

Whats going on here is we are treating the string as a list of characters, and we are telling python to give us the first `x` elements of the list (first `x` characters of string). Keep in mind, list slicing follows the syntax `list[start:end]` (in our case, `start` is implied to be 0). This means that, since lists start at 0, list slicing really returns a list of all elements with index from 0 (inclusive) to `x` (non inclusive).

For a better, more detailed explanation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7662085) great answer by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) on how list slices work.

Answer (score 2):

On an extra note, you can do lambda function.

```
yourFunction = lambda string, num: string[:num]

print(yourFunction("bobsyouruncle", 5))
```

returns

> bobsy

for reference:

[Python3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

[Python course Doc](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php)

Answer (score 1):

Python has some pretty powerful built in functionality. One of them (slicing) does exactly what you're asking for.

```
def rangeLoopStringParam1(chars, x):
    return chars[:x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly split you string using :

new_string = string[:n] with n being the length you want.